# Avoid page reload on Button click having onClick and onClientClick events in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3, code-behind, page-refresh

I have an Asp server control button for which I have `onClick` for processing code in code behind and `onClientClick` to process javascript code. The codes are:

**Update:** As per Icarus solution, updated codes :

Button source:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 648px; top: 202px; position: absolute" 
        Text="Show route" OnClientClick="droute(); return false" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdncroute" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; uid=root;password=as64ws;database=Gmaps"))
    da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from routes where uid='" + Session["uname"].ToString() + "'", con);
    da.Fill(ds, "mroute");
    foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        uroute.Add(r["latlng"].ToString());
    }
    croute = new string[uroute.Count];
    croute = uroute.ToArray();
    hdncroute.Value = string.Join("&", croute);
}
```

Javascript function:

```
function droute()
{
    var route=[];
    var temp;
    temp = eval(document.getElementById('<%= hdncroute.ClientID %>').value);
    route= temp.split('&');
    //Polyline icon n line settings
    var iconsetngs= {path:google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW, fillColor:'#FF0000'};
    var polylineoptns= {strokeColor:'#3333FF',strokeOpacity:0.8,strokeWeight:3,map:map,icons:[{icon:iconsetngs,offset:'100%'}]};
    polyline= new google.maps.Polyline(polylineoptns);

    //Loop to add locations and draw line
    var path= polyline.getPath();
    for(var i=0;i<route.length;i++)
        {
            var marker= new google.maps.Marker({position:route[i],map:map});
            path.push(route[i]);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',showiwindow);
        }

    //Event Listener's
    function showiwindow(event)
    {
    iwindow.setContent("<b>Coordinates are:</b><br/>Latitude:"+event.latLng.lat()+"<br/>Longitude:"+event.latLng.lng());
    iwindow.open(map,this);
    }  
}
```

I know that writing `return false` for javascript function will avoid refresh, and also onClick has void return type. But still my page reloads on button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error here:

```
route = document.getElementById('<%= croute %>').value;
```

It should be:

```
route = document.getElementById('<%= croute.ClientID %>').value;
```

**Update:**

Markup - declare a hidden element in the page

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="hdnCroute" runat="server" />

//code behind

int [] croute = ... 

hdnCroute.Value = "["+string.Join(",",croute)+"]";
```

Now Javascipt:

```
//now you have an array back in javascript 
var route= eval(document.getElementById('<%= hdnCroute.ClientID %>').value);
```

Comment: I tried it. I get an error saying: `'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ClientID' and no extension method 'ClientID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
`

Comment: what kind of element is croute then? Isn't croute a server control? if it isn't why are you doing `<%= croute %>`?

Comment: No. croute is an array declared in the code behind in the page scope. 
`public string[] croute;`

Comment: Sorry I am a noob in javascript. Do only server controls require <%= %> syntax to be accessed in javascript?? Then how can I access this array?

Comment: You can't do that. You need to put the elements of the array in text format (concatenating them somehow). Then use a hidden element, set its value to the text generated from the array and then read the value on javascript as I showed you. I will provide an example for you. Sit tight.

Comment: Thanks that solved an issue. But my page still reloads in browser and also I dint get this: `"["+string.Join(",",croute)+"]";`.

Comment: My croute has elements like this: `croute[0]= 12.34,32.11` `croute[1]=43.23,22.1`, etc. So the above string.join isn't working

Comment: Go ahead and fix it, I am sure you can write code to concatenate strings.

Comment: Yep wil do that. What about page refresh on button click. That still persists. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

why the page reload?

```
OnClientClick="droute(); return false"
```

at inner of browser like this:

```
button.onclick = function(){
    droute(); 
    return false
};
```

while droute is going wrong,so,`return false` doesn't work.

Comment: I dont get you. Where do I write the button.onclick... in button source? It should be onClientClick right because its a javascript function? Also why _route = document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>').value;_ ? route should be reading an array of code behind. o_O